# How to using Oauth2 token SSO from another website to login/register on Drupal 8 website automatically

Tags: drupal, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, drupal-8

Sorry I am newbie in Drupal, I was trying Drupal 8 as my website, I have token generate from SSO base on Oauth2 from another website(not Drupal) which is contains uid, name, and some credential. I want to create user with uid from token automatically if not exist in local user db and automatically login if user exist in db or after creating user.
I have try [External Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/externalauth) module but because there is no documentation, I don't know what must I do to implement this module.

Hope some master can guide me to implement token

What I want is:

1. How to create function with specific url contains token
2. Get uid etc base on token then login automatically
3. How to logout if we using SSO from other website?

Thanks, for your help